# Are affine functions compactly-supported only when they are zero

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, affine-geometry, support-function

#### Question:

If $f$ is an affine map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ then must $f$ be [supported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#Essential_support) on some affine subspace of positive dimension if and only if $f\neq 0$?  So in particular $f$ is never compactly supported unless it is $0$?

In the multivariate case, I define the "support" of a measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ as
$$
\operatorname{supp}(f) \triangleq \overline{\left\{
x \in \mathbb{R}^n:\, \|f(x)\|_{\mathbb{R}^m}>0
\right\}}.
$$

---

#### Here's what I've got (so far...):

---

Let $f(x) = Ax +b$ for some $n\times m$ matrix $A$ and some $B \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  If $A\neq 0$, then the support of $f$, denoted $\operatorname{supp}(f)$, is equal to
$$
\operatorname{supp}(f)
=
\mathbb{R}^n-[\ker(A)-b],
$$
where $X-b:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:\, x+b \in X\}$ and $\ker(A)$ is the kernel of the linear map $A$.  In particular, $\operatorname{supp}(f)$ is a *closed* (affine) subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

By rank-nullity (or the splitting Lemma really...)  and the fact that $A \neq 0$ (so $Im(A)\neq 0$) we have
$$
\dim(\ker(A)) = n - \dim(Im(A)) < n.
$$
So $\operatorname{supp}(f)$ is a closed affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of (topological) dimension $n - \dim(Im(A))>0$ (and of dimesional $0$ iff $A=0$ and $b=0$).

So $f$ is compactly-supported if and only if $f=0$, in which case $\operatorname{supp}(f)=\emptyset$.

Comment: The map $(x_1,x_2) \mapsto x_1$ is supported on a line of dimension $1<2$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write compactly-supported

Comment: The zero set $Z$ of an affine function is affine. If the dimension of $Z$ is the same as the ambient space then the function is zero, otherwise it is non zero on the complement which is unbounded. Hence $Z$ is compact **iff** the function is zero.